# How to Click on a check box using selenium web driver using Java?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to click on a check box of an associated Part Number, which is different column.

In the below example. I want to click on check box that is associated to **XP206** part.

```
<span id="p3BQp2" class="z-label" style="width: 75px;">**XP206**</span>
```

How can I do it using selenium Webdriver in Java?

Comment: Provide correct `html` code for required element and `java` code that you've tried already

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.Id("p3BQp2")).click();
```

or

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("XP206")).click();
```